# error using php and curl sending api request

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending API request using curl and php. The first one works but not the second one. Error shows that postfields data is empty, or the whole request is null. I'm confused.

this is my code

```php
$request_id = "aaa7996d-8d5c-4116-b759-6afb1c84ff39";
$res_url = "http://opeapi.ws.pho.to/getresult";
$res_data = array('request_id'=>$request_id);
$res_ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($res_ch, CURLOPT_URL, $res_url);
curl_setopt( $res_ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($res_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$res_data);
curl_setopt($res_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$results = curl_exec($res_ch);
curl_close($res_ch);
var_dump($results);
```

but the results returned:

```
SecurityError612Bad, invalid or empty REQUEST_ID parameter.
```

Here are a few things I tries:

```php
$res_data = array('request_id'=>urlencode($request_id));
$res_data = "request_id=".$request_id;
$res_data1 = json_encode($res_data);
$res_data1 = http_build_query($res_data);

$res_url = "http://opeapi.ws.pho.to/getresult?request_id=aaa7996d-8d5c-4116-b759-6afb1c84ff39";
```

none of them really works.

but the curious thing is I have another request before this one. Also using Pho.to API. I processed a photo using their parameters and got the result using curl and php. That one works (that's why I get the request_id to obtain the processing result)

this is my former request. it works, why not the second one??

```php
$data = '(some xml parameters)';

$sign_data = hash_hmac('SHA1', $data,'***');
$url = "http://opeapi.ws.pho.to/addtask";
$posting = array('app_id'=>'***','key'=>'***','sign_data'=>$sign_data,'data'=>$data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$posting);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

error message suggest there is no request_id...
or the whole request $curl is null...

Any help or suggestion will be deeply appreciated!!! Please~Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you sure your request_id value is correct?

Comment: yes I'm sure, because when I enter the requesting url along with request_id, I can get the results successfully. like http://opeapi.ws.pho.to/getresult?request_id=...(this is a demo, the id might expire now)

Comment: Looking at the docs, the request that uses the Request ID parameter is in response to a previous task. It's possible that this request should only be performed via GET - your first example is POSTing the request ID.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

It turns out I'm supposed to use a get request (in order to get my data), not a post.
So I directly write my url to...http://***?request_id=***, and deleted all the option lines about request (because the default process is get, not post), and it worked!
took me 7 hours to figure this out...TAT